# Header On TemplateField In GridView

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, header

How to create Header "Full Name" in GridView when I am creating "TemplateField" with hyperlinks ? For example I want these rows in TemplateField to have header "Full Name".

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")  %>'
                     NavigateUrl="CarTest.aspx" > </asp:HyperLink>        
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you all who answered. The big question is how to do it from code  behind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the header template:

```
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
               ....................
          </ItemTemplate>
          <HeaderTemplate>
                Full Name
         </HeaderTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

For more information, [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")  %>'
                 NavigateUrl="CarTest.aspx" > </asp:HyperLink>        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                                                        <asp:GridView ID="grdDisCategry" runat="server" CssClass="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped" Font-Size="Small"
                                                                            EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#cc0000" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="10" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Arial"
                                                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Record Found" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#990000">
                                                                            <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                                    <HeaderTemplate>

                                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthsDays" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm m-bot15"
                                                                                            Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Bind("MonthsDays") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthDays" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm m-bot15"
                                                                                            Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Bind("MonthDays") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" VerticalAlign="Top"
                                                                                Font-Bold="true" />
                                                                            <RowStyle Font-Size="Small" Height="1" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Italic="true" />
                                                                        </asp:GridView>
```