# how to bind value of a textbox in gridview header

Tags: c#

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />         
<div>   

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
        </asp:GridView>

 </div>
```

how to pass `textbox` value into `gridview` header which are columns.

```
  DataTable dt =new DataTable();
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Columns.Add("TextBox1.Text");
        GridView1.DataSource =dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Use header Template. Below link explains how to - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633735/header-on-templatefield-in-gridview

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `dt.Columns.Add("TextBox1.Text");` to `dt.Columns.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim());`

**Note:** I have removed the " inside ADD method. And one more suggestion, after adding column add rows with data into datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a submit button and write the code

```
        DataTable dt =new DataTable();
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Columns.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        GridView1.DataSource =dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Make sure your gridview have AutoGenerateColumns property to "True"